# New-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'co' is specified more than once

Tags: powershell

I saw some questions which has kinda the same title, but none of them solved my problem, I don't get why I get this error. Here's my code :

```
$NORMAL_ACCOUNTS = Import-Excel -Path "data_norm.xlsx"

$TEMPLATE_NORMAL_ACCOUNT = Get-ADUser anUser -Properties c, CN, co, Company, Country, Description, DisplayName, DistinguishedName, employeeType, GivenName, Manager, Name, Organization, otherMailbox, preferredLanguage, PrimaryGroup, SamAccountName, sn, StreetAddress, Surname, Title, UserPrincipalName
$TEMPLATE_NORMAL_ACCOUNT.UserPrincipalName = $NULL

$OTHER_EMAIL = $NULL

FOREACH($NORMAL in $NORMAL_ACCOUNTS)
{

    $OTHER_EMAIL = @("$($NORMAL.otherMailbox)")

    New-ADUser `
        -Instance $TEMPLATE_NORMAL_ACCOUNT `
        -c "$($NORMAL.c)" `
        -CN "$($NORMAL.CN)" `
        -co "$($NORMAL.co)" `
        -Company "$($NORMAL.Company)" `
        -Country "$($NORMAL.Country)" `
        -Description "$($NORMAL.Description)" `
        -DisplayName "$($NORMAL.DisplayName)" `
        -DistinguishedName "$($NORMAL.DistinguishedName)" `
        -employeeType "$($NORMAL.employeeType)" `
        -GivenName "$($NORMAL.GivenName)" `
        -Manager "$($NORMAL.Manager)" `
        -Name "$($NORMAL.Name)" `
        -Organization "$($NORMAL.Organization)" `
        -otherMailbox $OTHER_EMAIL `
        -preferredLanguage "$($NORMAL.preferredLanguage)" `
        -PrimaryGroup "$($NORMAL.PrimaryGroup)" `
        -SamAccountName "$($NORMAL.SamAccountName)" `
        -sn "$($NORMAL.sn)" `
        -StreetAddress "$($NORMAL.StreetAddress)" `
        -Surname "$($NORMAL.Surname)" `
        -Title "$($NORMAL.Title)" `
        -UserPrincipalName "$($NORMAL.UserPrincipalName)" `
        -AccountPassword (Read-Host -AsSecureString "INPUT USER PASSWORD") `
        -Enabled $FALSE

}
```

And I get (in French) this error :

```
New-ADUser : Impossible de lier le paramètre, car le paramètre «co» est spécifié plusieurs fois. Pour fournir plusieurs valeurs aux paramètres qui les 
acceptent, utilisez la syntaxe de tableau. Par exemple, «-parameter valeur1,valeur2,valeur3».
Au caractère D:\Users\pmonties\OneDrive - Professional\Documents\VARONIS - I-TRACING\CREATE_ACCOUNTS.ps1:22 : 9
+         -co "$($NORMAL.co)" `
+         ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterAlreadyBound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

I tried to remove the "co" attribute part from the code, and then I get this error :

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument “FR”
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Let me guess: You removed the named parameter `-co` but left the argument that was bound to it `"$($NORMAL.co)" ` in place?

Comment: Debug your code and check to see if `$NORMAL.CN` and `$NORMAL.co` have valid values.  This feels like a bad parameter.

Comment: I did print the values to check if they were correct, and actually the were @Matthew.

Comment: And nope @ManuelBatsching

Comment: What are the intended arguments for `-sn`, `-co`, `-c`, `-CN` ? I suspect that they duplicate named parameters, that are also given, like `-Country`, `-Company` and `-Surname`. Can you verify that, by comparing the values `$NORMAL.co` to `$NORMAL.Country` etc?

Comment: replace ALL your parameter names with the FULL names. according to the MSDocs site, there are THREE that start with `co`, and there are EIGHT that start with `c`. there are NONE that are just `c` and there are NONE that are just `co`.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try to clean some of the attributes ! Thanks for the advices

Comment: Have you tried just changing your -Properties [yuck] to -Properties * ?  That should clearly indicate if it's your Properties array.

Comment: Actually no wouldn't work with -Properties *, raises an error when you are creating users with New-ADUser

Comment: Actually Worked ! I obviously should've rely on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd378959(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN . Didn't know they were valide attributes while creating an user. Thanks !

Comment: As aside, may I draw your attention to [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)? This will help you to stop using all those horrible backticks and make the code much easier to maintain.

Comment: Easier to maintain indeed ! I'll use this as of now, thanks